# Plotting points using usmap and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, usmap

I currently have to an excel datasheet of longitudes, latitudes, and a third category called "quarter" and here's how I'm plotting it:

```
plot_usmap("states")+
  labs(title="US Property Deletions by Quarter")+
  geom_point(data = long_lats,
             aes(x=lat, y=lon, color=quarter),
             size = 1)
```

This is my output:

[image]

The "quarter" breakdown appears exactly how I want, but none of the points are plotting from the datasheet. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. If you want to post your data type `dput(long_lats)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(long_lats, 10))` for the first ten rows of data.

Comment: This said: There is a red dot somewhere in South Dakota.